# Query to add sum of received products and subtract sum of shipped products to inventory

Tags: sql, ms-access

For each warehouse, I need to get the estimated quantity of each product. This quantity is calculated from the quantity noted in the last inventory, minus shipments since this last inventory, plus resupplies since this last inventory.

Here are my entities:

```
-warehouse
  location
-inventory
  date
-product
  name
-inventory_product
  quantity
  warehouse_id
  product_id
  inventory_id
-resupply
  date
-resupplying
  resupply_id
  product_id
  warehouse_id
  quantity
-shipment
  date
-shipping
  shipment_id
  product_id
  warehouse_id
  quantity
```

I'm thinking of something along the line of...

```
select distinctrow product.name, inventory_product.quantity - sum(shipping.quantity) as quantity
from inventory
inner join inventory_product on inventory.id = inventory_product.inventory_id
inner join product on inventory.product_id = product.id
inner join shipping on (inventory_product.warehouse_id = shipping.warehouse_id and inventory_product.product_id = shipping.product_id)
inner join shipment on shipping.shipment_id = shipment.id
where inventory.date <= shipment.date
group by shipping.product_id;
```

But I can't see how to add in the resupplying part...

Comment: Does *product*, *inventory*, and *shipment* tables not have keys? As is this query is not valid in MS Access as `JOIN` pairings require parentheses. Use query designer to help.

Comment: All entities have id properties as primary keys of course. I don't have Access and cannot run my query. I'm doing it to help someone.

Comment: @nicomp Well, I'm helping someone by spending days teaching him database design, including notions like primary key and foreign key, for which I have to use analogies like a street number on a mail box and the same number on the mail. I do it because he has no way to achieve this project on his own. Regarding this request, I did spend some time trying to create it, as you can see in my question, but I could not complete it. So, yes I'm asking help here, so as to help someone else, someone who could not even write this question, let alone write in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider breaking apart unit level and aggregate level parts then join them back together for final arithmetic expression. Save each as stored queries to be referenced in other query's `FROM/JOIN` clauses.

**Last Inventory Date Query** *(aggregate by product_id)*

```
SELECT i.product_id, Max(n.date) AS MaxInvDate
FROM inventory AS n 
INNER JOIN inventory_product AS i ON n.id = i.inventory_id
GROUP BY i.product_id;
```

**Shipment Sum Query** *(sums qty on and after above's MaxInvDate)*

```
SELECT i.product_id, i.quantity AS inv_qty, idt.date AS inv_date, 
       SUM(s.quantity) AS shipment_qty    
FROM ((inventory_product i INNER JOIN inventory idt ON idt.id = i.inventory_id)     
INNER JOIN (shipping s INNER JOIN shipment sdt ON sdt.id = s.shipment_id) 
   ON s.product_id = i.product_id)    
INNER JOIN LastInvDateQ l
   ON l.product_id = i.product_id AND idt.date = l.MaxInvDate    
WHERE sdt.date >= l.MaxInvDate    
GROUP BY i.product_id, i.quantity, idt.date
```

**Resupply Sum Query** *(sums qty on and after above's MaxInvDate)*

```
SELECT i.product_id, i.quantity AS inv_qty, idt.date AS inv_date, 
       SUM(r.quantity) AS resupply_qty    
FROM ((inventory_product i INNER JOIN inventory idt ON idt.id = i.inventory_id)     
INNER JOIN (resupplying r INNER JOIN resupply rdt ON rdt.id = r.resupply_id) 
   ON r.product_id = i.product_id)    
INNER JOIN LastInvDateQ l
   ON l.product_id = i.product_id AND idt.date = l.MaxInvDate    
WHERE rdt.date >= l.MaxInvDate    
GROUP BY i.product_id, i.quantity, idt.date
```

**Final Query**

```
SELECT s.product_id, s.inv_date, s.inv_qty, s.shipment_qty, r.resupply_qty, 
       (s.inv_qty - s.shipment_qty + r.resupply_qty) as estimated_qty
FROM ShipQtyAggQ s
INNER JOIN ResupplyQtyAggQ r ON (s.inv_date = r.inv_date) 
AND (s.inv_qty = r.inv_qty) 
AND (s.product_id = r.product_id);
```

*Of course you can nest each `SELECT` statement as derived tables in final query but may become difficult to read and/or maintain.*

Comment: I owe you a beer. Off topic, but your profile's linkedin link 404s.

Comment: Haha...glad I could help! Odd, my profile links work on my end. Maybe a regional/network access issue for you?

Comment: Even though I'm logged in, here is what LinkedIn has to say: "Profile Not Found The LinkedIn profile you're looking for isn't public or doesn't exist." High Chaparral...